# Check a zipcode in range with sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data like this

```
Country_name   | zipcode_from  |  zipcode_to
United Kingdom     JE1 OAA         JE4 9ZZ
United Kingdom     GY1 1AA         GY9 3ZZ
Spain              52001           52080
```

Now, I want to get row that have zipcode from range zipcode_from to zipcode_to.
Example: if the zipcode is 52005, so the result is:

```
Spain              52001           52080
```

If the zipcode is JE1 9AA, the result is

```
United Kingdom     JE1 OAA         JE4 9ZZ
```

I use sql in mySql.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ZipCodes WHERE zipcode_from <= '52005' AND zipcode_to >= '52005'
```

But it's going to be performed using standard string compare.

Comment: I think not simple like that. it will not get correct result if the zipcode 'JE1 9AA'